# Show/hide toggle with iframe - Jquery

Tags: iframe, jquery

I'm new in Jquery (learning from examples).
I'm trying to create some step by step tutorial and then to show FAQ with iframe at the end.

My main problem is that the page loads all my iframes (but hides them) so it takes about 10-15 seconds to load the page.

I want to be able to load each iframe by clicking on the button/text only, somehow I managed to to that (because my URL is the same and only the id of the url changes: http://my.nanorep.com/widget/widget.html?account=waze&kb=623233&onloadquestionid=**ID**)

Id: **3490608** or **3490611**

When I click on forgot password for example it shows the iframe but when I clicks on it again it doubles it, I have no idea how to make it hide/ removed/ show it once.

The code: http://jsfiddle.net/ronvaisman/SKBWA

(it's under **web** -> **Login Issue**

Thanks for the help,
Ron

Answer (score 3):

to show:

```
$('frameid').show();
```

to hide:

```
$('frameid').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working (I managed to hide it but again it duplicate the iframe each time I click on it).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example I made which has proven really useful as a starting point for these types of things.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <style>
 #click{ cursor:pointer;}
 .clickopen{ background-image:url(clickopen.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
 .clickclose{ background-image:url(clickclose.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
 <div id="box" style="width:800px; height:100px; background-color:#000; display:none;">
 </div>
 <div style="width:800px; height:100px;background-color:#CCC;">
 <div id="click" style=" width:213px; height:27px;" class="clickopen">
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script>

var clickTrue = 0;

//show dialog

$("#click").click(function () {

     $('.clickopen').toggleClass("clickclose");


    $('#box').animate({
    opacity: 0.75,
    height: 'toggle'
    }, 400, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
 });

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```